# Finding paths to files using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a function which opens a dialogue box and lets the user select a folder. This function returns a string which is simply the path of the folder selected.

```
FolderPath = BrowseForFolder()
```

Now the idea is that this `FolderPath` refers to a special folder which has tons of excel (.xml) files in it. What I wish to do is get specific location (which has their names) for each of these .xml files in this special folder. I don't want the user to select all the filer, since there will be a lot of them. So in short, i want lots of strings denoting paths to these .xml files in `FolderPath`

Comment: You say "I don't want the user to select all the folders". Does this mean that there are sub-folders under the `FolderPath` folder, or did you mean to say that "I don't want the user to select all the **files**"

Comment: sorry i meant 'files', not 'folders', i fixed it :)

Comment: @SahilChaudhary its still not entirely clear.  Are you looking to restrict users to only selecting a single file?  Or just a small subset of files in a folder?

Comment: Let me try to be more clear. The user selects the folder which has a lot of files in it. Now that I know that the files are at say C:\whatever\, i need to extract files locations such as C:\whatever\file1.xml, C:\whatever\fileAnother.xml, C:\whatever\fileOneMore.xml etc. From there my intention is to extract data from these files which is possible once I know their names and exact locations

Comment: You can use `Dir(C:\whatever\*.xml)` to loop through all xml files in the selected folder.  Tons of examples here on SO alone.

Answer (score 0):

Sahil, I would do this with a scripting object.

```
Dim FileCollection as Collection
Dim FSO as Scri[ting.FileSystemObject
Dim FLD as Scripting.Folder
Dim FIL as Scripting.File
```

You have to set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library, or declare them all as Objects and use CreateObject to build them on the fly.  Use Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath) to connect the object with your path string.  Then use For Each FIL in FLD.Files to loop through the contents looking for xml files, and put them into the collection with FileCollection.Add File.Path.